# Animar color fondo labels al cambiar propiedad

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, axml

A ver quien me puede ayudar con esto. Estoy intentando animar un color de fondo de un label al hacer este visible o invisible. Tengo esto pero no funciona.

```
<Style x:Key="esperando" TargetType="Label">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <ColorAnimation 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                             From="Black" To="#FFCB0101" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" 
                                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>                    
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

No se exáctamente cómo se llama la propiedad a cambiar.
LO que quiero es hacer que la animación forme parte de ese estilo de entrada y poner el estilo en el diccionario. Y tiene que ser al cambiar la propiedad visible porque quiero aprender a hacerlo, ya he visto por ahí ejemplos para cambiar estilos con un evento.

Alguna idea? gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Haga la animación con blend for visual studio. Eso le genera el código automáticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, según entiendo, lo que quieres es que al cambiar la visibilidad de un `Label` se cambie el color de fondo del mismo.. NO el `Foreground`, sino el `Background`, del mismo modo entiendo que si seteo un `Label` a `Hidden` el color de fondo debería quedar `Transparent` por defecto... y todo eso usando un Diccionario de Recursos.

En ese caso mi solución es la siguiente:

NOTA: Lo que hace este ejemplo es animar el fondo de un Label de Transparente a Rojo cada vez que se cambie la visibilidad de ese Label de Hidden o Collapsed a Visible.

**PASO 1:**
Crea el diccionario (`ResourceDictionary`) y deberá lucir así (yo lo llamé Label.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF6B6B6B"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=IsVisible}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation 
                            Duration="00:00:1"
                            From="Transparent"
                            To="Red" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>            
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**PASO 2:**
Crea una instancia global del diccionario, eso hará que el efecto se aplique a TODOS tus Labels..

```
<Application x:Class="MiAplicacion.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Label.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

si solo lo quiere aplicar en algunos Labels específicos, agrégale un `x:Key` al style..

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="LabelConEfecto" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">      
        ...     
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Y le agregas a tus Labels la etiqueta Style:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource LabelConEfecto}" />
```

Y listo.. 
Prúebalo y avísanos si es lo que buscas.

Saludos!

Comment: Tu solución funciona. Pero no sé por qué, y eso me pone muy nervioso de narices XDDD A ver... por qué hace falta la parte de cambiar el control template y además he quitado la parte de ControlTemplate.triggers dejando solo lo de Border Borderbrush y sigue funcionando. tengo que mirar trozo de código y ver que hace ,uf   Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. ç

Comment: Cuando quiera estimado... aquí quedo atento a más preguntas.